# UserID returning (not set) (Google Analytics)

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics

Inside the reports for some of the custom events we have setup, the User_ID is set to 0/(not set), and if we do a comparison with "all users" and "Signed in with UserID" there is a difference. Thus some users are able to trigger the event without having a UserID? Which should not be possible because these events are triggered after login and the assigning of userID is assigned at login?

What possible reason could the UserID be set to 0 or (not set)?

```
await analytics().setUserId(internalUserID);
```

Additional Information:

- We use: '@react-native-firebase/analytics'
- Tested locally via GA debug view and the userID is assigned everytime

Answer (score 0):

There was an edge case where the setUserId was bypassed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).